# Why passing a std::make_pair to a map::insert is not working?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, reference, std

I was playing with a C++ API that returns a `const std::vector<uint8_t>&`. I tried to store it into a `std::map` for further use and noticed that due to the `const` nature of the object, I cannot assign it to the map with `[]`. So, I used `insert` instead but came across a strange behavior when the `std::make_pair()` function is directly called into the `insert` function without any temporary variable.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

int main(){
    std::map<const std::string, const std::vector<uint8_t>&> vectest;
    std::vector<uint8_t> val1 = {0x0, 0x1};
    std::vector<uint8_t> val2 = {0x0, 0x1};
    std::vector<uint8_t> val3 = {0x0, 0x1};

    std::string key1 = "test1";
    std::string key2 = "test2";
    std::string key3 = "test3";

    auto pair = std::make_pair(key1, val1);
    vectest.insert(pair);
    vectest.insert(std::make_pair(key2, val2));
    vectest.insert(std::make_pair(key3, std::cref(val3)));
    std::cout<<"test size map : "<<vectest.at(key1).size()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"test size map : "<<vectest.at(key2).size()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"test size map : "<<vectest.at(key3).size()<<std::endl;
}
```

And here's the output:

```
test size map : 2
test size map : 0
test size map : 2
```

I read somewhere that `std::make_pair` may not support references and that I should maybe use `the std::cref(val2)` instead. But I don't understand at all what is going on under the hood.

Does anyone have an idea what is going here?

Comment: `make_pair()` returns a temporary `std::pair<std::string, std::vector>` (no references - it _copies_ `val1`/`val2`). Your `vectest` stores a reference to the `vector` _of that temporary_, so that reference becomes invalid right after `insert` completes (because the temporary is dead). Trying to read from it (e.g. to get the size) is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Isn't that an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @BenjaminBihler Yes, but I'm sure there's a dupe somewhere that this question should be closed with (the author mentioned as much). Terrible reason, I know, but I'm hoping someone else finds a good dupe target. Trying to find those is borderline frustrating with the current tools.

Comment: @BenjaminBihler Point in case: I couldn't find the dupe with the close dialog search. Had to go to google (using the same keywords).

Comment: @MaxLanghof Now I am content. ;-)